# Повторить SQL-запрос в цикле даже если WHERE дублируется

Tags: php, mysql

Есть входной массив, каждый элемент которого содержит артикул товара и название склада например:

```
$inputArray = array(
    '001|Основной',
    '002|Основной',
    '002|Дополнительный'
);
```

Как видно один и тот же товар может быть на двух разных складах, т.е. артикул может повторяться. С определённой таблицы MySQL нужно взять айди этих товаров по их артикулах
Например имеем таблицу **#__products**:

```
id  artikul
1   001
2   002
```

Когда пытаюсь выполнить запросы в цикле:

```
foreach($inputArray as $row) {
    $parts = explode('|', $row);
    $artikul = $parts[0];
    $sklad = $parts[1];
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM #__products WHERE artikul = '.$artikul;
    ...
    // дальше в этом же цикле нужно вставить айди товаров и названия складов во вторую таблицу
    $insert = 'INSERT INTO second_table (`id`,`sklad`) VALUES ('.$id.', '.$sklad.')';
}
```

То получаю ошибку **1066 Not unique table/alias** и это понятно. Но мне нужно чтобы запросы к MySQL все же выполнились в цикле столько раз, сколько элементов имеет входной массив даже если WHERE в запросе дублируется. Так нужно потому что получив айди товаров дальше в этом же цикле нужно вставить во вторую таблицу названия складов с полученными с первой таблицы айди товаров (во второй таблице есть отдельный столбик с AUTO_INCREMENT).

Возможно ли выполнить такие запросы с WHERE-дубликатами и если да то как?

Comment: *То получаю ошибку 1066 Not unique table/alias и это понятно* - а что понятно, объясните пож-ста тем, кто в танке

Comment: Понятно то что запрос не выполняется потому что WHERE artikul  дублируются, два раза WHERE artikul = 002 т.е. не уникальные, насколько понимаю

Comment: это не про это.  это у вас в запросе одна и таже таблица больше одного раза присутствует. дальше в ошибке имя быть должно

Comment: И очень похоже, что ошибка вообще не в приведенных тут запросах, тут такой ошибки в принципе быть не может